# Footer fijo en la pantalla se esconde

Tags: html, css, menu, footer, fixedheader

estoy teniendo un problema para un menú que se encuentra en el footer de la ventana.
Quiero que se muestre siempre.
Cuando inicia la página o se scrollea para subir, el footer se esconde.

[image: Menu en mala posicion]

En cambio cuando se scrollea para abajo el menú aparece (como quiero que se vea en todo momento).

[image: Menu esperado]

Le agregué un color de fondo para que se note más.

---

Este es mi código:

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer"> </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
//Mobile 440px
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 440px) {
    #footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;

        height: 55px;
        width: 440px;
        z-index: 2000;

        //background:#fff;
        background:red;
    }
}
```

Estoy muy seguro que el problema es por la position fixed. Pero sin usar esa propiedad no sé como hacer para que siempre se muestre abajo de la página.

Comment: se esconde un poco o entero como si estuvieras bajando el contenido de la pagina?

Comment: Lo máximo que se esconde es lo que se ve en la imagen.

Comment: probaste el codigo que deje?

Comment: Sip. No me funciona, sigue todo igual :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mí me ocurrió eso mismo el año pasado trabajando con un Prestashop. Al final encontré un elemento de la página que se salía de la pantalla por un padding, esto cambiaba el tamaño del body y provocaba un pequeño scroll.

Comprueba los elementos que puedan salirse de su espacio, y los que tengas con posiciones absolute o fixed, tal vez puedas corregirlo añadiendo a ese elemento o al elemento padre un "overflow: hidden"

Comment: Muchas gracias, iba por el lado de el padding y saltos de lineas.

Answer (score 0):

Usa la etiqueta footer mejor que un div con id="footer

```
<footer>
<!--Contenido-->
</footer>
```

Prueba a darle al footer margin: 0;

```
  footer{
    position:fixed;
    left:0em;
    bottom:0em;
    height: 2em;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0em;
}
```

Luego con `padding`, `height` y `widht` lo pones a tu gusto para que cuadre mas o con `margin:0em;`

Comment: Ya tiene esa propiedad.

Comment: si perdona no puse todo el codigo. Tambien te diria que usaras la etiqueta footer en vez de un div con el id footer.